# Renaming multiple files of varying lengths to last 16 characters

Tags: file, batch-file, rename

I have the following documents in a folder

How do I rename them to include only the last 11 characters?

```
123_abcdefghijk.doc to abcdefghijk.doc
1234_abcdefghikh.doc to abcdefghikh.doc
12345_abcdefghijl.doc to abcdefghijl.doc
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Should have also included that I'd like to do this via batch file

Comment: Where are you getting stuck?  Looping through the files?  Obtaining the last 11 characters of the file name?  Performing the rename option?  Creating a batch script?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested

```
@echo off

set "doc_dir=c:\docs"

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

pushd "%doc_dir%"

for %%# in (*.doc) do (
    set "docname=%%~n#"
    set "docname=!docname:~-11!"
    rem !!! remove the echo if ren command looks ok !!!!
    echo ren "%%~f#" "%%~dp#!docname!.doc"
)

endlocal
```

Comment: got this one to work for me as well  for %%i in ("*.doc") do (set fname=%%i) & call :rename
goto :eof
:rename
ren "%fname%" "%fname:~-20%"
goto :eof

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1*delims=_" %%a in (*_*.doc) do ECHO(ren "%%a_%%b" "%%b"
```

(as a batch line - from the prompt reduce `%%` to `%`)

Assumed that you want to perform the task in the current directory.

Assumed that you actually want to delete the leading string up to and including the `_` from the filename.

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.

Answer (score 0):

Like @npocmaka's solution..  However..

Where you have:

```
echo ren "%%~f#" "%%~dp#!docname!.doc"
```

You need to check/re-check:

```
if not exist "%%~dp#!docname!.doc" ( ren "%%~f#" "%%~dp#!docname!.doc"
) else ( echo "%%~dp#!docname!.doc" already exists >> error_log.out )
```